# Is it possible to have "pseudo route" in Angular 4+

Tags: angular, navigation, angular-router

I'm trying to understand how to create multiple routes that all points towards the same component, but that it adjust some filter accordingly to the active route.

For example I have multiple routes here:

```
const routes: Route[] = [
{
  path: '',
  component: HelloComponent
},
  {
    path: 'Test',
    component: HelloComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'Truth',
    component:HelloComponent
  }
];
```

And this one component (just pasting the reaction of this component) :

```
constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  activeRoute.url.subscribe(x => {
    let paths: string[] = x.map(y => y.path);
    let concated = paths.join() || "";

    if(concated == "Test")
      this.value = "This is a test"
    else if(concated == "Truth")
      this.value = "This is not a lie";
    else
    this.value = "Base value. Nothing to see here";
  });
}
```

Why I'm doing this is for easier navigation in my component. This removes some click that the user have to do to get where he wants to get.

My questions is: Is there another way to acheive the same functionnality?

The link to the stackblitz reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-53400902